# how to pass an external variable to a query in python

Tags: python, sql, excel

how to pass an external variable to a query in python?
Under my code

```
import openpyxl
import numpy as n
import pandasql as ps
from openpyxl import Workbook
import datetime
import pandas as pd


df2 = pd.read_excel(r'Desktop\esempio__base__2022032040_SIM.xlsx', sheet_name="quotazioni")
df3 = pd.read_excel(r'Desktop\esempio__base__2022032040_SIM.xlsx', sheet_name="polizze")
df4 = pd.read_excel(r'Desktop\esempio__base__2022032040_SIM.xlsx', sheet_name="att")

dataf2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
dataf3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
dataf4 = pd.DataFrame(df4)


data_ultimo_valore_quota_1 ="SELECT max(dataf2.d_riferimento) FROM dataf2, dataf3 where dataf3.NAV = dataf2.i_quotazione "
data_ultimo_valore_quota=(ps.sqldf(data_ultimo_valore_quota_1))
controvalore_iniziale =  "SELECT d_inizio FROM dataf4 where  d_inizio < %(data_ultimo_valore_quota)s "
```

I want to pass the variable in the last query: data_ultimo_valore_quota

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to acomplish. Do you want to pass command line arguments? Do you want direct user input? Something else? All these are possible.

Comment: I want to pass the "data_ultimo_valore_quota" argument in the query that extracts "controvalore_iniziale". I want to set the condition in query : where  d_inizio<data_ultimo_valore_quota

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to perform string formatting. Python provides multiple ways to do this. See https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ for some options.

In your case, one option is to do something like

```
controvalore_iniziale = f"SELECT d_inizio FROM dataf4 where d_inizio < {data_ultimo_valore_quota}"
```

Comment: I still have a problem, the query print all the values ​​of the table and does not read the condition in the "where " of query : " where d_inizio < '{data_ultimo_valore_quota}'". The variables "data_ultimo_valore_quota" and "d_inizio " are date, how should i format?

Comment: The date format depends on your database. Figure out what date format your database expects, and you can use the Python `datetime` module to convert the date to the correct format.